# Chrome does not show pictures inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, inline

Has anybody ever encountered the problem that pictures are not shown `inline` in the Google Chrome browser, even though i.e. `display:inline-block`and other css codes were used? In any other browser everything is depicted as it was intended. However, the 4th picture is only suddenly in another row when the site is being opened in Chrome.

The problem looks like this: [image: problem]

Code:

HTML

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>


<li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">1981-1990</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                    <p>Some more text</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="timeline-picture-body">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            </div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
/*body*/
body {
 background-color: white;
}
.panel {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
.panel-extra {
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.box {
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 border-bottom-width: 3px;
 border-bottom-color: lightgrey;
 border-bottom-style: solid; 
}
/*Timeline*/

.timeline {
list-style: none;
padding: 20px 0 20px;
position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}

.timeline > li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    }

.timeline > li:after {
    clear: both;
    }

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-right-width: 15px;
        left: -15px;
        right: auto;
    }

    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-right-width: 14px;
        left: -14px;
        right: auto;
    }
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body: before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        right: -15px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: 15px solid transparent;
        border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
        content: " ";
    }
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body: after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        right: -14px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: 14px solid transparent;
        border-left: 14px solid #fff;
        border-right: 0 solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
        content: " ";
    }
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body {
        float: left;
    }
.timeline-title {
 margin-top: 0;
 color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-body > p + p {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.timeline-images-right {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.timeline-images-left {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.padding-bottom {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.align {
 display: block;
}

/*fonts*/
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 220px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
.box h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: black;
}
p {
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the sample code?

Comment: @LeonLaci Added the complete code

Comment: You should've just added the code that is specific to this problem, not the whole code. And where are your body tags?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem you have in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LzLvpgng/

Comment: It is not the entire code of the website, just of the styles and the relevant html block. Because of that there are also no body tags as they are in the below the header and above the relevant code part. However, the problem does not lie in the code, I have tried everything in a jsfiddle and it worked perfectly fine. I assume that there must be some default function by Google Chrome that changes something. But I am no expert, therefore, the question above. If you prefer, I can insert body tags in the code above.

Comment: Try using reset.css http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ or normalize.css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: I am not really familiar with these stylesheets. Won't their usage interfere with the other styles of my website?

Comment: Those stylesheets are going to reset the browser defaults.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114315/discussion-between-leon-laci-and-elina).

Answer (score 1):

Since bootstrap is being used, inserting `<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>` after the second picture in the code fixed the problem.

```
            <div class="timeline-picture-body">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            </div>
```